# Using keywords in Django for a URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url

I am trying to use keywords in my Django URl but it will not allow me. I have tried the syntax of about 7-8 peoples projects and none of them have worked...

So basically I have a class with user info and one of the attributes it contains is "first_name", obviously representing the first name of the users in the database.

So basically, according to my app,
userData/index   :    brings up a list of all users
userData/1      : brings up the info of the user with the ID of 1

```
The code for this is...
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', welcome),
    path('userData/', include('userData.urls')),
]
```

This is the code from my project url folder^

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import admins, index, ratings

urlpatterns = [
    url('admins', admins, name='admins'),
    url('index/', index, name='index'),
    url('user_id', ratings, name='rating')
]
```

Now here is where the problem is, the keyword user_id simply prints literally the characters user_id as a string in the url bar when I want it to print the user id.

I just dont know what to write in place of 'user_id'..
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your project url from

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import admins, index, ratings

urlpatterns = [
    url('admins', admins, name='admins'),
    url('index/', index, name='index'),
    url('user_id', ratings, name='rating')
]
```

to

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import admins, index, ratings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admins', admins, name='admins'),
    path('index/', index, name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ratings, name='rating')
]
```

Comment: I got an error: TypeError: ratings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: was userData/index working for you ? if yes then should as well.

Comment: you have just one urls.py file ?

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to put pk as an argument for my ratings view, that fixed it

Comment: glad I could help. dont forget to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to get the PK to show up on an html page?

Comment: @EnzoRomano. add it to context from your views. then you will have access in html page